# Como fazer exibição dinâmica em HTML+PHP?

Tags: php, html, layout, entrada-de-dados

Estou estudando HTML e PHP, mas tem coisas que não estou conseguindo descobrir como faz. Afinal como obtenho dados de entrada para processá-los? Como no teclado com aqueles campos de texto `<input type="text">`. E, depois disso, como adapto a interface da página ou a atualizo com a nova interface em função dos dados coletados?

Para facilitar, coloquei um exemplo onde se fornece um tamanho de matriz quadrada e de acordo com o valor fornecido a interface da página disponibiliza células para serem preenchidas. O gif abaixo ilustra de forma bem simples essa ideia, mostrando as mudanças da página a cada modificação da string no campo "ordem".

[image: Gif simples ilustrativo de exemplo de dinâmica de página web em HTML/PHP.]

Já agradeço antecipadamente a quem me esclarecer.

Comment: Esse tipo de modificação é feito por JavaScript, não PHP. O que sabe de JavaScript?

Comment: para passar as variáveis pro PHP é usado geralmente `$_POST['exemplo']` ou `$_GET['exemplo']`, que pega o valor do `<input name="exemplo">`, quanto à matriz, apesar de ser MUITO mais fácil com JS, também é possível via PHP, através de `forech` e uma `<table>`

Comment: Obrigado. Descobri aqui como se faz mais ou menos.

Comment: somente php dinamicamente sem att página nao é possível... apenas usando ajax ou javascript, pois nao atualiza a página

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri como faz, sem a necessidade de ajax, javascript, table e outros. Vou explicar com o exemplo. Fiz a interface dinâmica de matriz quadrada toda no arquivo "index.php".

Primeiramente, coloco o campo que deve atualizar a interface. Usando `<form action="index.php" method="post">`, a entrada pelo campo `<input name="numeroDeEquações" type="text" />` vai reabrir a página "index.php" com a variável `$_POST['numeroDeEquações']` atualizada com o valor que foi passada no campo.

O segundo e último passo é determinar a interface de acordo com o valor do campo. Para isso, primeiramente verifico se `$_POST['numeroDeEquações']` foi definido. Depois verifico se o valor é válido. De acordo com as condições, se constrói a interface.

Simples assim. Segue o código e agradeço a todos que tentaram ajudar.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Matriz Quadrada</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            Ordem: &nbsp&nbsp <input name="numeroDeEquações" type="text" /><br />
        </form>

        <?php
            $inválido = true ;
            if( isset($_POST['numeroDeEquações']) ){
                $numeroDeEquações = $_POST['numeroDeEquações'] ;
                if( $numeroDeEquações>1 && $numeroDeEquações<10 ){
                    $inválido = false ;
                    for( $índice1=0 ; $índice1<$numeroDeEquações ; $índice1++ ){
                        for( $índice2=0 ; $índice2<$numeroDeEquações ; $índice2++ ){
                            echo( "<input size=1 type='text' />" ) ;
                        }
                        echo( "<br>" ) ;
                    }
                }
            }
            if( $inválido ) echo( "<br>Forneça um número de 2 a 9." ) ;
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse código funciona, mesmo com acentos nos nomes das variáveis?

Comment: Sim, se escolher arquivo de texto com caracteres utf-8 sem bom...